# confused by MDN description on 'Function', Function.length is property of Function or Function.prototype

Tags: javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

It said that

```
Properties and Methods of Function
```

> The global Function object has no methods or properties of its own, however, since it is a function itself it does inherit some methods and properties through the prototype chain from Function.prototype.

then it continued to say that

```
Function prototype object 
Properties

Function.arguments 
An array corresponding to the arguments passed to a function. This is deprecated as property of Function, use the arguments object available within the function instead.
Function.arity 
Used to specifiy the number of arguments expected by the function, but has been removed. Use the length property instead.
Function.caller 
Specifies the function that invoked the currently executing function.
```

> Function.length   (!!!here is what I confused, why it does not display **Function.prototype.length**)

```
Specifies the number of arguments expected by the function.
Function.name
The name of the function.
Function.displayName 
The display name of the function.
```

> Function.prototype.constructor

```
Specifies the function that creates an object's prototype. See Object.prototype.constructor for more details.
Methods
```

just wonder if Function.length is the property of Function.prototype?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN docs on `Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length):

> The `Function` constructor is itself a `Function` object. Its `length` data property has a value of 1.

`Function.length` equals `1`, because the `Function` constructor takes one formal argument—the function body.

> The `length` property of the `Function` prototype object has a value of 0.

`Function.prototype.length` equals `0`, because `Function.prototype` doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: but it said 'Function object has no methods or properties of its own, however, since it is a function itself it does inherit some methods and properties through the prototype chain from Function.prototype.' I think it should be Function.prototype.length

Comment: @arachide I don't think that's true. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Function)` returns `["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype"]`.

Comment: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Function.prototype) returns [length, name, arguments, caller, apply, bind, call, toString, constructor]

Comment: @arachide Yes, and so what?

Comment: why for constructor it displayed 'Function.prototype.constructor' but for length it displayed 'Function.length'